# Get whole row by two unique fields in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried to achieve this for the last few hours with no luck so I am appealing for help.

I have a google form which saves to a google spreadsheet and the responses are recording in a structure as per below.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------
|  WEEK  |  CATEGORY  |  COL1   |   COL2   |  TIMESTAMP   |
|--------|------------|---------|----------|--------------|
|  1     |  CAT1      |  VALUE1 |  VALUE1  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  1     |  CAT1      |  VALUE2 |  VALUE2  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  1     |  CAT2      |  VALUE1 |  VALUE1  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  2     |  CAT3      |  VALUE1 |  VALUE1  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  2     |  CAT3      |  VALUE2 |  VALUE2  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a formula which I can use in google sheets to take the most recent entry where WEEK and CATEGORY together are unique values.

Eg using the above table, the formula would result in something that looks like this.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------
|  WEEK  |  CATEGORY  |  COL1   |   COL2   |  TIMESTAMP   |
|--------|------------|---------|----------|--------------|
|  1     |  CAT1      |  VALUE2 |  VALUE2  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  1     |  CAT2      |  VALUE1 |  VALUE1  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
|  2     |  CAT3      |  VALUE2 |  VALUE2  |  YYYY-MM-DD  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a super clean solution for what is basically a dynamic self-join in SQL parlance, but this might be manageable:

1. Get a list of maximum timestamps per category and week
   [image]
2. Filter the original table by this derived list using a concatenated key
   [image]

Any attempts to improve this answer appreciated (in particular the string concatenation as key is not very elegant).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for you help!